# How do I close the dialog properly , if the dialog is opened by mainframe

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a mainframe and clicked the pushbutton to open a new dialog ,

the dialog have a timer , let the timer to show message at 3sec interval ,

but if I click the top right close button to close the dialog , the messagebox still run ,

how to avoid it ?

Thanks!

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QTabWidget,QWidget
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMessageBox,QFileDialog,QErrorMessage
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class UI_Test20(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test202):
        Test202.setObjectName("Test202")
        Test202.resize(100,100)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test202)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb.setText('push button!')
        Test202.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        self.retranslateUi(Test202)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test202)

    def retranslateUi(self, Test202):
        Test202.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Test202", "MainWindow", None, -1))

    def btnClicked(self):
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog1(self)
        self.ui.show()

class Test20(QMainWindow, UI_Test20) :

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Test20, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

and the dialog code

```
class Ui_Dialog1(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.p = parent
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(3000) 
    def update(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self,'123','123')

    def setupUi(self, Dialog1):
        Dialog1.setObjectName("Dialog1")
        Dialog1.resize(333, 173)
```

main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Test20(None)
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: handle close event, when this event occur, close QMessageBox.

Comment: how can I actually destroy the dialog?

Comment: I changed my answer below, It worked fine in PyQt4. Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call show() method with QDialog your dialog will be modeless and will be hidden not deleted when it's close. To make sure your dialog deleted add one more line in your dialog init method:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Ui_Dialog1, self).__init__(parent)
    self.p = parent
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
    self.timer.start(3000)
    #Make sure that your dialog will be deleted not hidden
    self.setAttribute(QtGui.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
```

Comment: `QMessageBox.information()` is a static method and does not return any `QMessageBox`, this returns the button presses the associated `QMessageBox::StandardButtons`

Comment: thanks @eyllanesc for correct me, I edited my post and tested carefully :).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful @You'reawesome!